# Why can't set a variable value of a viewController by using another viewController?

Tags: ios, swift

I know this is Duplicate Question, but i didn't find the solution for my problem. I have two controllers. HomeViewcontroller's variable of "myValue"'s value can't be set by using ViewController class.I don't know the issue here but code is working without error.But when i print "myValue" it shows nil.Destination view controller is not the controller that i want to set variable value. Destination view controller is a tab bar controller, so i want to set the variable value of first tab bar and second tab bar view controllers. This is my code :-

```
import UIKit

  class ViewController: UIViewController { 

   override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {

    if(segue.identifier == "gotoHome") {
        println("1111")

        var storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        var viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("HomeViewController") as! HomeViewController
        viewController.myValue = 8888


         }

      }


  }
```

this is the other view controller

```
import UIKit

 class HomeViewController: UIViewController {

   var myValue: Int!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
       println(myValue)

       }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to instantiate the viewcontroller, as it is already been done, you just need to fetch the viewcontroller for the current segue operation, so your code should look like below

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {

    if(segue.identifier == "gotoHome") {
        println("1111")

        let controller = segue.destinationViewController as! UITabBarController
        let homeController = controller.selectedViewController as !HomeViewController
        homeController.myValue = 8888


     }

}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: problem is that destination view controller is not the controller that i want to set variable value.

Comment: @ChathurangaSilva Then you need to change the segue connection to proper VIewController you want to push.

Comment: he's printing the value in `viewDidLoad`, which is called when the view gets loaded from the storyboard. At that point `myValue` does not have a value yet because it is set after instantiating the view.

Comment: but, my case is destination view controller is a tab bar view controller , so i want to set variable value of the first tab of the tab bar view controller. So how could it can be done ?

Comment: Can you put breakpoints and check whether the objects have correct Controllers?

Comment: Sure, I'll check on that !

Answer (score 1):

Change to :

```
let viewController = segue.destinationViewController as! HomeViewController
```

Comment: problem is that destination view controller is not the controller that i want to set variable value.

Comment: The destination controller is not the HomeViewController ?

Comment: Nope, When navigate to another view controller, I need to set another view controller's varibale. Not segue destination view controller's varibale

Comment: Simply store that value in your model and get it back when that controller is loaded. Take a look at http://www.raywenderlich.com/86477/introducing-ios-design-patterns-in-swift-part-1

Answer (score 0):

You're printing the value of `myValue` in `viewDidLoad` which is called when you're instantiating it from your storyboard. You're setting `myValue` after creating your instance. Try to print `myValue` in `viewWillAppear` for example, then it should be set.